# Using @Primary in Spring Data JPA repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

If someone ever needed to use @Primary on Spring Data repositories:
It looks like Spring Data JPA ignores `@Primary` annotations on repositories.

As a workaround I have created `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which checks if given repository has `@Primary` annotation and sets that bean as primary.

This is the code:

```
@Component
public class SpringDataPrimaryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    public static final String REPOSITORY_INTERFACE_PROPERTY = "repositoryInterface";


    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        makeRepositoriesPrimary(getRepositoryBeans(beanFactory));
    }

    protected List<BeanDefinition> getRepositoryBeans(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        List<BeanDefinition> springDataRepositoryDefinitions = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);

            String beanClassName = beanDefinition.getBeanClassName();
            try {
                Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(beanClassName);
                if (isSpringDataJpaRepository(beanClass)) {
                    springDataRepositoryDefinitions.add(beanDefinition);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new ApplicationContextException(String.format("Error when trying to create instance of %s", beanClassName), e);
            }
        }

        return springDataRepositoryDefinitions;
    }

  protected void makeRepositoriesPrimary(List<BeanDefinition> repositoryBeans) {
    for (BeanDefinition repositoryBeanDefinition : repositoryBeans) {
        String repositoryInterface = (String) repositoryBeanDefinition.getPropertyValues().get(REPOSITORY_INTERFACE_PROPERTY);
            if (isPrimary(repositoryInterface)) {
                log.debug("Making site repository bean primary, class: {}", repositoryInterface);
                repositoryBeanDefinition.setPrimary(true);
            }
    }
}

protected boolean isSpringDataJpaRepository(Class<?> beanClass) {
    return RepositoryFactoryInformation.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass);
}

private boolean isPrimary(String repositoryInterface) {
    return AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(getClassSafely(repositoryInterface), Primary.class) != null;
}

    private Class<?> getClassSafely(String repositoryInterface) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(repositoryInterface);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ApplicationContextException(String.format("Error when trying to create instance of %s", repositoryInterface), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And your question is???

Comment: what @Primary ? in which package/software is this annotation?

Comment: @Primary is a Spring annotation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: Cannot resolve method `isSpringDataJpaRepository()`.

Comment: Thx mk321, I have updated the code

Comment: Today i face this problem when I realized I can't make fake implementations for unit tests because in app container throws exception about unambiguous beans, so I will check your solution and thank you in advance!

Comment: After 2 little changes: `Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(beanClassName == null? "TestName" : beanClassName` instead of `Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(beanClassName)` and remove throwing Exceptions few lines later: `throw new ApplicationContextException(String.format("Error when trying to create instance of %s", beanClassName), e);` cause I got `null` as bean name everything works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying the solution to spring boot application having two Mongo repositories.
But it was not able to find `repositoryInterface` in propertyValues.
Further investigation revealed that there is an attribute to identify the repository interface `factoryBeanObjectType`.

So changing the code in method `makeRepositoriesPrimary()`from:

```
String repositoryInterface = (String) repositoryBeanDefinition.getPropertyValues().get(REPOSITORY_INTERFACE_PROPERTY);
```

To:

```
String repositoryInterface = (String) repositoryBeanDefinition.getAttribute("factoryBeanObjectType");
```

worked as expected.

Hope this helps.