# How to get the Spring Data JPA Repository Factory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Since I got no answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496823/primary-equivalent-for-autowired-spring-jpa-repositories) I tried to tweak the example given in the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) for customizing repositories. There ist a Method `getRepository(Class repositoryInterface)` which looks like It ist the right place to map my repository Overrides:

```java
public class MyRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

        return new MyRepositoryFactory<>(entityManager);
    }

    private static class MyRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Resource
        private Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> overrideRepositories;

        public MyRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;

            //Test
            overrideRepositories = new HashMap<>();
            overrideRepositories.put(CustomerRepository.class, Customer2Repository.class);
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            return super.getTargetRepository(metadata);
            // return new MyRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>)
            // metadata.getDomainClass(), entityManager);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the
            // JpaRepositoryFactory
            // to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
            return JpaRepository.class;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public <E> E getRepository(Class<E> repositoryInterface, Object customImplementation) {
            if (overrideRepositories != null) {
                Class<?> override = overrideRepositories.get(repositoryInterface);
                if (override != null) {
                    repositoryInterface = (Class<E>) override;
                }
            }
            return super.getRepository(repositoryInterface, customImplementation);
        }
    }
}
```

I configured it like this: `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass=MyRepositoryFactoryBean.class)`

Normally you would autowire the repositories themselves which doesn't work because there are two Interfaces with the same Type and [I don't know how to tell Spring which one to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496823/primary-equivalent-for-autowired-spring-jpa-repositories).

If I autowire the factory instead, I can call `getRepository` each time I need a specific one. But how do I get this factory? Does Spring Data JPA somehow expose this as a bean? I can't find anything on google concerning this. Or is this approach entirely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ApplicationContext` instance to get your `MyRepositoryFactoryBean` bean class. All you have to do is implement the `ApplicationContextAware` interface in order to get access to the `ApplicationContext` instance.

```
  public class myClass implements ApplicationContextAware{
    
        private static ApplicationContext ac;
        
            @Override
            public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
                this.ac = applicationContext;
            }
        
        }
```

Now you can use `ac.getBean("MyRepositoryFactoryBean")` to get the factory directly from the `ApplicationContext`. Once you have that bean you can call `getRepository` on it.